# VBA Outlook: How to get the smtp address of the selected folder account

Tags: vba, email, outlook, directory

I have different accounts in my Outlook.
Depending on the currently selected folder, I would like to find the smtp Email address of the corresponding account.
(Folder name is no help)

I know how to get the smtp email address of an account:
(olApp.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress)

I know how to get the current selected folder or even its store name:
(olApp.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.store.DisplayName)

but I can't find how to link both information...

Any idea ?

thx :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub storeAddress_from_DisplayName()

Dim storeDisplayName As String
Dim storeSMTPAddress As String

Dim storeRecipient As Recipient

' DisplayName and PrimarySmtpAddress can be the same

storeDisplayName = ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Store.DisplayName
Debug.Print " storeDisplayName: " & storeDisplayName

Set storeRecipient = Session.CreateRecipient(storeDisplayName)

If storeRecipient.AddressEntry.Type = "EX" Then
    storeSMTPAddress = storeRecipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
    Debug.Print " storeSMTPAddress: " & storeSMTPAddress
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Keep in mind that name resolution will fail if there is a contact with the same name (I have at least a few). Also keep in mind that in older versions of Outlook the store name could be prefixed with "Mailbox ". This is not something I'd use in production code.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you could parse the EX store entry id to extract the EX address and then use it to build the GAL entry id that you can use to call `Namespace.GetAddressEntryFromID`. You can see how the store entry is parsed (in C++) in the [MFCMAPI source code](https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi).

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, it exposes [RDOExchangeMailboxStore](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdostore.htm#RDOExchangeMailboxStore).`Owner` property (returns [RDOAddressEntry](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAddressEntry.htm) object, which in turn exposes the `SMTPAddress` property):

```
Set MySession = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
MySession.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
set Store = MySession.GetStoreFromID(Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.StoreID)
MsgBox Store.Owner.SmtpAddress
```